# In flickity, how can I use arrowkeys without leftclick or tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickity

[this is Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/)

I cannot express in English clearly, so if possible please help editing my question.

This is my web *page*

```
https://codepen.io/haozun/pen/ywNjvQ
```

When I open this *page*, I cannot use arrowkey to navigate different carousel-cell.

I can only use arrowkey **after** I have mouse clicking on that page.

How can I edit the code so that I can use **arrowkey** at the very beginning without click on it? i.e. I open this page in my browser, and then I can use arrowkey(37,39) to rotate it immediately. I want to use the keyboardHandlers once I open the page

```
Flickity.keyboardHandlers = {
// left arrow
37: function() {
  var leftMethod = this.options.rightToLeft ? 'next' : 'previous';
  this.uiChange();
  this[ leftMethod ]();
},
// right arrow
39: function() {
  var rightMethod = this.options.rightToLeft ? 'previous' : 'next';
  this.uiChange();
  this[ rightMethod ]();
},
```

};

I can edit all source code, including `flickity.pkgd.min.js`. And my page only contains one flickity.

[image]

The official site tells we must use tab (or leftclick) first, then we can really use arrowkeys to change cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It almost impossible someone-else will answer this question, And the former answerer has rejected my edit, so I have to answer myself.

Adding this to JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  init();
});

function init() {
  let flkty = new Flickity(".carousel");
  flkty.focus()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `Flickity` instance when your app initializes, then call `next()` on it. You can see in the demo below that as soon as you load your app, it will scroll to the next item in the carousel:

```js
let flkty;
const delayMs = 1000;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  init(true);
});

function init(shouldAutoScroll) {
  flkty = new Flickity(".carousel");

  if (shouldAutoScroll) {
    //Start an carousel auto scroll
    autoScroll();
  } else {
    //Just flip to next item and that's it..
    flkty.next();
  }
}

function autoScroll() {
  if (flkty) {
    setInterval(function() {
      flkty.next();
    }, delayMs);
  }
}
```

```css
.carousel-cell {
  min-height: 30em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 3em 0 3em;
  width: calc( 100vw - 9em);
  max-width: 40em;
  box-shadow: 0px 16px 20px 5px #7777;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="carousel" id="main" data-flickity='{ 
    "cellAlign": "center",
    "contain": true,
    "adaptiveHeight":true,
    "freeScroll": false,
    "accessibility":true,
    "wrapAround": true,
    "setGallerySize":true,
    "hash":true,
    "selectedAttraction": 0.05,
    "friction": 0.3,
    "prevNextButtons":false
    }'>
    <div class="carousel-cell" id="carousel-cell1">1LONGLONGLONGLONG</div>
    <div class="carousel-cell" id="carousel-cell2">2LONGLONGLONGLONG</div>
    <div class="carousel-cell" id="carousel-cell3">3LONGLONGLONGLONG</div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>

</body>
```